# applet does not work on chrome

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, applet

Hi I am using below code in asp file for applet, but applet does not load in google chrome while it is working fine in Internet Explorer.

```html
<object classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" width="1100" height="500" hspace="0" vspace="0" align="middle" name="graph" 
     codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.6.0/jinstall-6u31-windows-i586.cab#Version=6,0,0,5"
     id=JavaBeansBridge_Object1>

     <PARAM NAME ="CODE" VALUE="com.test.Graph" >
     <PARAM NAME ="CODEBASE" VALUE="/test/applet/" >
     <PARAM NAME ="ARCHIVE" VALUE="graphing.jar">
     <param name="GraphType" value="<%= GraphType%>">
     <% if GraphType = "1" then %>
         <param name="GraphTitle" value="Monthly">
     <% else %>
         <param name="GraphTitle" value="Daily">
     <%end if %>
    <param name = "type" value = "application/x-java-applet;version=1.6">
</object>
```

I test other applet web sites in my chrome they work, although require update plugin but when I click on run this time then applet work. But my applet does not work while work in IE

Please tell me where is the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are using ERB; can you post the raw output? Perhaps there is a formatting error.

Also, check out the [Java deployment advice](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html). In particular, instead of doing things in HTML, try using the `deployJava.js` script. This script will also check that the browser is compatible and that the JRE is available.

```javascript
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    var attributes = {codebase:'/test/applet/',
                      code:'com.test.Graph',
                      archive:'graphing.jar',
                      width:1100, height:500} ;
    var parameters = { ... your application parameters } ;
    var version = '1.6' ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
```